# MongoDB: How to apply multiple $project on aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Given below is a sample document from the `my_collection`

```
{
  "_id":ObjectId("5b3f4e1013aad111501b34c4")
  "Text":["kjsdf sdfjgnks vk ekl sdsdd."],
  "Title":["lkdjf wufk"],
  "List":["3412","1244","7654","8476"],
  "__v":0
}
```

I want to aggregate over `my_collection` such that:

1. A field "totalList" is generated which would contain the count of items in the array in the field "List".
2. Prevent field "__v" from showing up in the result.
3. Change the Value of the output field "List" to a join of the array
4. Remove the trailing comma at the end of the string in "List"
5. Cut short the string generated by the 4th point to contain only the first 50 characters in the field of "List"

So I wrote this code:

```
  db.my_collection.aggregate( 
      [ 
         {
           $addFields: {
             totalList: { $size: "$List" }  // I can achieve the 1st point with this
           }
         },
         { $project : { 
                          __v:0,  // I can achieve the 2nd point with this
                          List:
                          {
                            $reduce:  // I can achieve the 3rd point with this
                               {
                                 input: "$List",
                                 initialValue: "",
                                 in: { $concat : ["$$value", "$$this", ","] }
                               }
                          }
                       }
          }
      ] 
  );
```

However, I'm getting the following error when I run the above command:

```
  Failed to execute a script.

  Error:
  Assert: command failed: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "Bad projection specification, cannot include fields or add computed fields during an exclusion projection: { __v: 0.0, List: { $reduce: { input: \"$List\", initialValue: \"\", in: { $concat: [ \"$$value\", \"$$this\", \",\" ] } } } }",
    "code" : 40182,
    "codeName" : "Location40182"
  } : aggregate failed
  _getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
  doassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:16:14
  assert.commandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:370:5
  DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1319:5
  DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@:1:355
  @(shell):1:1

  Error: command failed: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "Bad projection specification, cannot include fields or add computed fields during an exclusion projection: { __v: 0.0, List: { $reduce: { input: \"$List\", initialValue: \"\", in: { $concat: [ \"$$value\", \"$$this\", \",\" ] } } } }",
    "code" : 40182,
    "codeName" : "Location40182"
  } : aggregate failed :
  _getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
  doassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:16:14
  assert.commandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:370:5
  DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1319:5
  DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@:1:355
  @(shell):1:1
```

Hence, I rewrote it to:

```
  db.my_collection.aggregate( 
      [ 
         {
           $addFields: {
             totalList: { $size: "$List" }  // Achieve the 1st point with this
           }
         },
         { $project : { 
                          "Text":1,
                          "Title":1,
                          __v:{     // Achieve the 2nd point with this
                              $cond: {
                                 if: { $eq: [1,1] },
                                 then: "$$REMOVE",
                                 else: 0
                              }
                          },
                          List:
                          {
                            $reduce:  // Achieve the 3rd point with this
                               {
                                 input: "$List",
                                 initialValue: "",
                                 in: { $concat : ["$$value", "$$this", ","] }
                               }
                          }
                       }
          }
      ] 
  );
```

Now, I could achieve the first 3 points.
However, how can I achieve the 4th and 5th point?

Comment: add the fields `_v` and `List` using `$addFields` and then use `$project` at the end of the pipeline

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet, actually, I want to not show `__v` in the output and compute few things over `List` as mentioned in point numbers 1,3,4 and 5. See the sample document format in my question description.

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/ARkehwIFqjc try this using [`substr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/)

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet, this is brilliant! But I tried wrapping `$rtrim` also the way you did `$substr`, it worked on mongoplayground.net but not on my local mongodb. You can find my updated code here https://mongoplayground.net/p/UL981zPWSxj

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try below aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "totalList": { "$size": "$List" },
    "List": {
      "$substr": [
        { "$reduce": {
          "input": "$List",
          "initialValue": "",
          "in": { "$concat": ["$$value", ",", "$$this"] }
        }},
        1,
        50
      ]
    }
  }},
  { "$project": { "List": 1, "Test": 1, "Title": 1, "totalList": 1 }}
])
```

Output

```
[
  {
    "List": "3412,1244,7654,8476",
    "Title": [
      "lkdjf wufk"
    ],
    "_id": ObjectId("5b3f4e1013aad111501b34c4"),
    "totalList": 4
  }
]
```

Try it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/e0jG1_ghkQ9)

Comment: this is brilliant! But I tried wrapping `$rtrim` also the way you did `$substr`, it worked on mongoplayground.net but not on my local mongodb. You can find my updated code here https://mongoplayground.net/p/UL981zPWSxj

Comment: @TempO'rary What is your mongodb version? Because `$rtrim` has introduced in version 4.0 which is the latest one... But you can use above aggregation it will work from 3.6 as well

Comment: ohh! mine is 3.4. So, then, how can I trim leading and trailing comma?

Comment: Oh so your only change was placement of comma in here `"$concat": ["$$value", ",", "$$this"]` and made second parameter of `"$substr"` to 1. Is that correct? Nothing else changed, right?

Comment: precisely... @TempO'rary

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following aggregation. I have mentioned the changes for #4 and #5 in comments below.

```
db.sample.aggregate( 
    [ 
     {
       $addFields: {
         totalList: { $size: "$List" } //This is for #1
       }
     },
     { $project : { 
                      "Text":1,
                      "Title":1,
                      "totalList":1,
                      __v:{     
                          $cond: {
                             if: { $eq: [1,1] }, //This is for #2
                             then: "$$REMOVE",
                             else: 0
                          }
                      },
                      List:
                      {
                        $reduce: //This is for #3
                           {
                             input: "$List",
                             initialValue: "",
                             in: {
                                   $concat: [
                                     "$$value",
                                     {
                                       $cond: { 
                                         if: { $eq: [ "$$value", "" ] }, //This is for #4
                                         then: "",
                                         else: ", "
                                       }
                                     },
                                     "$$this"
                                   ]
                                 }
                           }
                      }
                   }
      },
      {
        $project : { 
                      "Text" : 1,
                      "Title" : 1,
                      "__v" : 1,
                      "List" : { $substr: [ "$List", 0, 50 ] }, //This is for #5
                      "totalList":1
        }

      }
    ] 
);
```